# Lodash. How to groupBy except undefined

Tags: javascript, lodash

Trying to group up array of object to get unique properties with Lodash

But it takes `undefined` like unique property if property does not exists

Is there way how to avoid it? and left only existing properties ?

So i'm going to achieve only `My Office 1` but with my solution getting 
`undefined` and `My Office 1`
**Example array**

```
[
        {office: null},
        {office: 
            {
                name: 'My Office 1'
            }
        }
]
```

**code**

```
Object.keys(_.groupBy(arr, 'office.name')).map((office, index) { ... }
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. `undefined` is a valid grouping in this case. You'll have to do a filter before or after your `groupBy`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just filter out the objects, which do not have the path.

```js
let objects = [
  {office: null},
  {office: {name: 'My Office 1'}},
  {office: {name: 'My Office 2'}},
  {office: {name: 'My Office 1'}},
];

let path = 'office.name';
let grouped = _(objects)
  .filter(object => _.has(object, path))
  .groupBy(path)
  .value();

console.log(grouped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```